# Exclude dependencies in AnnotationProcessorPaths

Tags: maven, dagger-2, maven-compiler-plugin, auto-value

I have the following build configuration:

Parent POM:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <release>11</release>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
          <path>
            <groupId>com.google.auto.value</groupId>
            <artifactId>auto-value</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.5</version>
          </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

One of the child project contains the following:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
          <path>
            <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>dagger-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>2.24</version>
          </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

When I run this configuration, I keep getting an `org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException`:

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project imgn: Fatal error compiling
...
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Fatal error compiling
...
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.CompilerException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.squareup.javapoet.ClassName.withoutAnnotations()Lcom/squareup/javapoet/ClassName;
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.squareup.javapoet.ClassName.withoutAnnotations()Lcom/squareup/javapoet/ClassName;
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.squareup.javapoet.ClassName.withoutAnnotations()Lcom/squareup/javapoet/ClassName;
    at dagger.internal.codegen.langmodel.DaggerElements.getTypeElement(DaggerElements.java:105)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.InjectBindingRegistryImpl$BindingsCollection.shouldGenerateBinding(InjectBindingRegistryImpl.java:134)
    ...
```

When I check the dependencies of those artifacts, `com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.6.5` ([after checking parents](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.google.auto/auto-parent/7/pom)) depends on `com.squareup:javapoet:1.9.0`, and `com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.24` depends on `com.squareup:javapoet:1.11.1`.

When I check the [signature of `ClassName::withoutAnnotation` in `com:squareup:javapoet:1.11.1`](https://github.com/square/javapoet/blob/a5db06d05f8bd799cef194af28ace07427e2d07e/src/main/java/com/squareup/javapoet/ClassName.java#L67) is `public ClassName withoutAnnotations()`.

The [signature of `ClassName::withoutAnnotation` in `com:squareup:javapoet:1.9.0`](https://github.com/square/javapoet/blob/dfba6d7272931991e56b0d0ac4b969c17cd3f334/src/main/java/com/squareup/javapoet/ClassName.java#L61) is `public TypeName withoutAnnotations()`.

So indeed, there is a clash.

If it were normal dependencies, I'd know to use the `<exclusions>` tag, but in this case, if I add such tag, I get the following issue: `Cannot find 'exclusions' in class org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.DependencyCoordinate`.

So how do I fix such clash in `annotationProcessorPaths`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of version 3.11.0 of the maven-compiler-plugin, you can exclude transitive dependencies for `<annotationProcessorPaths>` as well:

```xml
<annotationProcessorPaths>
  <path>
    <groupId>com.google.auto.value</groupId>
    <artifactId>auto-value</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.5</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.squareup</groupId>
        <artifactId>javapoet</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </path>
</annotationProcessorPaths>
```

See also: [MCOMPILER-395](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-395)

Comment: Indeed, that's the ticket I opened back then. Good catch!

Answer (score 1):

You can manually override the version of JavaPoet by adding it directly as an annotation-processor path:

```xml
<path>
  <groupId>com.squareup</groupId>
  <artifactId>javapoet</artifactId>
  <version>1.11.1</version>
</path>
```

(We [did exactly that](https://github.com/google/caliper/commit/d5f762313f690c38302bcd4e411c15a4937b26ae#diff-600376dffeb79835ede4a0b285078036R189) for the same problem.)

Also, I have set into motion the process of updating AutoValue to avoid (for now) this problem. So far, that's meant just [this commit](https://github.com/google/auto/commit/db3fc6d39e1d7dc11505efefe67453407ffcc970#diff-ab134393317ae375a2bae87d8d485198R92).

(Also, a technical note: The clash isn't as bad as it initially looks: A version of `withoutAnnotations` that returns `TypeName` is present in the bytecode for both versions. That's because, in 1.10.0+, the compiler automatically generates a bridge method in addition to the "real" version that returns `ClassName`. I totally understood this immediately and did not at all file [a false bug report](https://github.com/square/javapoet/issues/741) ;))

Comment: Yes! This works! I had found a workaround by redefining both annotation processors at the same time in a specific order (dagger first, AutoValue second, I think), but that was flunky. This is consistent and works. Also, I don't know why asking AutoValue to update their dependency didn't come to mind.Thank you all the line down for doing the appropriate things!